# Insert Employee and their multiple address in different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am very beginner in c# and asp.net mvc platform , so one request when you are answering reply in some details so i can understand
This is the Case:

There is a Employee and it can have multiple address. In my view what i am doing is , when i am creating an employee , on the same view i have given admin choices that he can add his employees different address , but those address need to be in other table , as he can create as many address as he wants and he may not.

As i have done this using Entity FrameWork , so these are the classes

```
public partial class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            this.EmployeeAddresses = new HashSet<EmployeeAddress>();
            this.EmployeeDocs = new HashSet<EmployeeDoc>();
        }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string LoginName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EmployeeAddress> EmployeeAddresses { get; set; }

    }


public partial class EmployeeAddress
    {
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is the a sample of view page:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">                                                                                                                                                        
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName, new { @class = "form-control" })                                                              
    </div>
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">                                                                                                                                                        
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoginName, new { @class = "form-control" })                                                              
    </div>
```

**Like this properties of models are binded over here how do i find address table properties here only ?**

Comment: Assuming you including them in your select (.Include), they should be accessible in model.EmployeeAddresses. You'd probably use a foreach to display them in the view.

Answer (score 1):

As steve greene mentions, you be able to use the Include something like:

```
_dbset.Include(x => x.EmployeeAddress);
```

That should be on your initial select query, you can then go through the data set in your view and render the address, so just write your razor view out much like you have done above (but for your address view) and then encompass in a foreach loop something like the below:

```
foreach(var item in model)
{
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmployeeAddresses.AddressLine1)
}
```

You may wish to do some kind of a check first to see if they even have an address or more than one.